# Can I use the word "in" after "behind"?

Tags: grammar

> There is no rationality behind "in" the allegation made by him.

Can I use the word "in" after behind in the above sentence? Is it grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

This sentence makes no sense, and is grammatically wrong! It should be just

> There is no rationality behind the allegation made by him.